# Maven is looking for a repository which does not exist in settings.xml or pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, maven-jetty-plugin

I am working on this Maven web project using Intellij. Apache Maven is manually installed in the machine and settings.xml is empty.

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>abc-nexus</id>
        <url>http://abc:9090/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I do the mvn package using this :

```
-e -Dmaven.repo.local=E:/svn-source-codes/MyConnectorProject/local_maven_repository package
```

I do the mvn install using this:

```
-e -Dmaven.repo.local=E:/svn-source-codes/MyConnectorProject/local_maven_repository install
```

However, still when I trying to run this generated war file using `jetty:run`, it downloads jars from some unknown website and the log looks lie this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jetty-plugin:1.0.4:run-war (default-cli) @ crystal-assembly ---
Downloading: http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0.3/maven-settings-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0.3/maven-model-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.3/maven-project-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.3/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0.3/maven-profile-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.3/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.3/maven-plugin-api-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.3/maven-artifact-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.3/maven-project-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0.3/maven-settings-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0.3/maven-profile-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0.3/maven-model-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.3/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.3/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.3/maven-plugin-api-2.0.3.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.3/maven-artifact-2.0.3.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 49.993 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-24T17:23:16+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/46M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.MyProjectName.maven.plugin:maven-jetty-plugin:1.0.4:run-war (default-cli) on project crystal-assembly: Execution default-cli of goal com.MyProjectName.maven.plugin:maven-jetty-plugin:1.0.4:run-war failed: Plugin com.MyProjectName.maven.plugin:maven-jetty-plugin:1.0.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.3 from/to MyProjectName-nexus-public (http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): WrongAppServer: Unknown host WrongAppServer -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.MyProjectName.maven.plugin:maven-jetty-plugin:1.0.4:run-war (default-cli) on project crystal-assembly: Execution default-cli of goal com.MyProjectName.maven.plugin:maven-jetty-plugin:1.0.4:run-war failed: Plugin com.MyProjectName.maven.plugin:maven-jetty-plugin:1.0.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.3 from/to MyProjectName-nexus-public (http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): WrongAppServer
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal com.MyProjectName.maven.plugin:maven-jetty-plugin:1.0.4:run-war failed: Plugin com.MyProjectName.maven.plugin:maven-jetty-plugin:1.0.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.3 from/to MyProjectName-nexus-public (http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): WrongAppServer
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin com.MyProjectName.maven.plugin:maven-jetty-plugin:1.0.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.3 from/to MyProjectName-nexus-public (http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): WrongAppServer
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:218)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:402)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:102)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.3, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.3 from/to MyProjectName-nexus-public (http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): WrongAppServer
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:376)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:210)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.3 from/to MyProjectName-nexus-public (http://WrongAppServer:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): WrongAppServer
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:76)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: WrongAppServer
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1068)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:962)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:359)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: WrongAppServer
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1248)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1164)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:834)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:985)
    ... 13 more
```

Clearly, the repository it is trying to access doesnt exist (I tried manually). I know repositories can be set in pom.xml or settings.xml.
However, I couldn't find any reference to that WrongAppServer.
Could anyone please help regarding this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you sure your properties don't have you using the bundled maven that IJ selects be default in a new project?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Sorry I don't know how to check it. Could you please explain?

Comment: File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven. Confirm that the 'User settings file' is what you expect it to be, and the 'Maven home directory' is not one of the bundled versions.

Comment: Is abc-nexus a repository you own? Is it possible that you're using the wrong URL and it's doing a redirect to WrongAppServer as some way of telling you that you're using, well, the wrong app server?

Comment: Maven home dir: <path in my machine where maven installed>,  User settings file: nor overridden, however this path is an invalid one. this file doesn't exist. Should I use the path for settings.xml from my externally installed Maven?

Comment: Is abc-nexus a repository you own? YES. Is it possible that you're using the wrong URL? This URL does not work when I try to open in browser. it's doing a redirect to WrongAppServer as some way of telling you that you're using, well, the wrong app server? I guess not. This URL was being used previously. But, not anymore, the URL is changed now. I added the new URL in the question above.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, I tried to give valid (but default) settings.xml file in Intellij. It didn't work too :(

Comment: Can you execute "mvn --version" and tell us what the output is?

Comment: @aksappy . I did it. It shows : Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T21:39:06+02:00)
Maven home: E:\svn-source-codes\Myproject\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: E:\svn-source-codes\MyProject\jdk1.7.0_80\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "x86", family: "windows"